# How to select rows if data might not be ordered?

Tags: python, sqlite

How to select `Id` from `mod` table even if data given in the query is not in the same order as the one in my SQLite database?

`mod` table:

| Id | Secondary1 | Secondary2 | Secondary3 | Secondary4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | offense | tenacity | speed | defense |
| 2 | offense | speed | protection | potency |
| … | … | … | … | … |

For example if I have the mod with secondaries speed, tenacity, defense and offense I want the query output to be "1".

I made a query for every partial permutation (speed, tenacity, defense, offense; speed, defense, tenacity, offense; etc.) but it isn't a sexy solution and seems overkill.

Comment: Sometimes the easiest solution is to keep them alphabetically sorted (or sorted in a well-known order). In those cases the query becomes trivial.

Comment: Simple solution would be to sort the secondaries e. g. by alphabet when adding the rows to the database.

Comment: Use a different table design; `(id, secondary_stat)` and make sure never to have more than 4 records for a given id.

Comment: @TheImpaler I was doing it manually before, but then searched for a more suitable solution. You clearly have a point here, might be easier and prettier this way. Also i already have a enum for all those secondary stats so the order is already here. If you want to, you can make it an answer so I can accept it as the final response.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be to just use `IN` multiple times.

For example:

```
select * from t
where Secondary1 in ('speed', 'tenacity', 'defense', 'offense')
  and Secondary2 in ('speed', 'tenacity', 'defense', 'offense')
  and Secondary3 in ('speed', 'tenacity', 'defense', 'offense')
  and Secondary4 in ('speed', 'tenacity', 'defense', 'offense')
```